# Adding New instance to LB - Restrict IP Access

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have the following set-up on the ComputeEngine

Load Balancer (CDN/SSL Offloading)
1 x Instance Group containing 1 x Web-server

I am upgrading to a new webserver, so I have installed migrated my content to the new instance.  Now I require to add this instance to the LB, but I only want my Office IP to be passed to the new instance and not the public traffic, so I can test all my sites before switch off the old server.

So it would act like:

www.domain.com > If My office IP > Goto New Instance
www.domain.com > If other IPs > Goto Current Instance

I hope that makes sense?

I need to access the sites via domains to be able to validate all functionality is correct on the site before launching new instance to the public.

Comment: Could you please confirm on what type of [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#types_of_cloud_load_balancing) you are using and some more details on the backend which will help to understand the situation e.g. Whether the new and old  web servers on separate [backend services](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service)?

Comment: at the moment the new VM is not attached to anything. As far as I am aware GCP only has 1 LB type?

Comment: I have not moved to setting up whole new dev environment instead of trying to do it this way.

Comment: That's not something GCP load balancers can do, but could be configured with an nginx or haproxy instance.